# Guidelines for packaging web app

Tags: application-development, packaging, debian

For a while now, I'm trying to build an Ubuntu package for PPA upload, and facing all sort of issues understanding bzr dh-make and such. The package is web application (php-based). Most packaging guides out there are about compiled software, so I wonder if there's a guide for packaging things which don't require compilation? Google's being surprisingly helpless at that.

I was able to create deb package manually and set up a local repository, it was quite straightforward. What I'm trying to understand is how to create a source package for PPA upload, for something that doesn't need compiling.

I would highly appreciate any pointers in this regard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Packaging is too broad and changing fast. The documentation is always lagging back.

I'm not quiet familiar with such type of apps. But I may able to point you where you can start.

- `dh`/debhelper has many modes, if it can't detect your project you can enforce a mode using `--with ...` option in `debian/rules` file.
- Learn by real examples, open https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and search for php based project like Wordpress.

  1. Click on the main package.
  2. On the package page, look to right you should find the original source archive `.orig.tar.xz` and Debian packaging files `.debian.tar.xz` .

[image: Ubuntu package info page]